# Spring Integration DSL: How to refactor into Subflows?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

To make my Spring Integration DSL code more readable and modular, I would like to extract a complex operation like `.scatterGather()` into a subflow.

Take this as an example of how the code could look before the refactoring:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow testFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("test").get())
                .scatterGather(
                        s -> s
                                .applySequence(true)
                                .recipientFlow(getSubFlow2()),
                        g -> g.outputProcessor(MessageGroup::getOne))
                .log(INFO, m -> m)
                .routeToRecipients(route -> route
                        .recipientFlow(IntegrationFlowDefinition::nullChannel)
                        .get())
                .get();
}

private IntegrationFlow getSubFlow2() {
    return f -> f.handle((m, h) -> 42);
}
```

This is the part I would like to extract into it's own subflow and method:

```
                .scatterGather(
                        s -> s
                                .applySequence(true)
                                .recipientFlow(getSubFlow2()),
                        g -> g.outputProcessor(MessageGroup::getOne))
                .log(INFO, m -> m)
```

I'm imagining the result looking something like this:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow testFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("test").get())
                .someMethod(getSubFlow1())
                .routeToRecipients(route -> route
                        .recipientFlow(IntegrationFlowDefinition::nullChannel)
                        .get())
                .get();
}

private IntegrationFlow getSubFlow1() {
        return f -> f
                .scatterGather(
                        s -> s
                                .applySequence(true)
                                .recipientFlow(getSubFlow2()),
                        g -> g.outputProcessor(MessageGroup::getOne))
                .logAndReply(INFO, m -> m)
}

private IntegrationFlow getSubFlow2() {
    return f -> f.handle((m, h) -> 42);
}
```

Can this be done somehow with Spring Integration DSL ? How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `gateway(IntegrationFlow)` method of flow definition :

```
    /**

 * Populate the "artificial"

 * {@link org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMessageHandler} for the

 * provided {@code subflow}.

 * Typically used with a Java 8 Lambda expression:

 * <pre class="code">

 * {@code

 *  .gateway(f -> f.transform("From Gateway SubFlow: "::concat))

 * }

 * </pre>

 * @param flow the {@link IntegrationFlow} to to send a request message and wait for reply.

 * @return the current {@link BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition}.

 */

public B gateway(IntegrationFlow flow) {
```

Comment: Brilliant. It looks like `.gateway()` is exactly what I was looking for. Would it make sense to include `.gateway()` into the list of verbs/endpoints under https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-basics ? I made the false assumption that the list was exhaustive.

Comment: Also, I can't find examples of `.gateway()` in the spring-integration-samples not can I find much online in terms of Spring Integration DSL examples using this endpoint.

Comment: Yes, we can do that. I think it even deserves it own section in that DSL. Please , raise a GH issue and we address ASAP. I don’t think such a primitive deserves the whole independent sample though

Comment: Cool, thanks. Done. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3591